# why user redirection is working fine on internet explorer but not on other browser

Tags: users, redirection

i have drupal framework with authorized users (saml module). when user try to sign in by putting their credentials it takes them to dashboard page rather than the required page.
here weired thing is its happening on all the browser except internet explorer.
i have checked every settings regarding user, and cleared cache on all other browser but still the problem is same.
Can anyone is familiar this kin of issue.
i wonder why everything is working fine in internet explorer but not on other browser.

i appreciate if anyone can reply with suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to show us your code - the code that re-directs after a user is logged in.

Comment: here is the code of simplesaml php:-

Comment: Sorry - nothing attached.